# Detecting the number of opened tabs in browser

Tags: batch-file

I have a batch file that will open a lot of tabs. But I am afraid that it will crush my computer. Is there any way to detect the opened/used tab? Is it possible to pause when tabs are 50?

Here is my code:

```
    for /F "UseBackQ" %%M in ("%~dp0TrackingNumber.txt") do Call CheckM "%%M"
    goto :End

    :CheckM
    rem check if tabs not more than 50

    echo Browsing...
    start "" https://sample.com/apps/trackorder?tracking_number=%~1
    PING 127.0.0.1 -n 2 > nul
    Goto:eof

    :End
    echo Done Browsing!
    pause
```

Comment: Each tab is a single program plus the main window is a single program. Tasklist will give you an ide how many are open. See `tasklist /fi "imagename eq iexplore.exe" /v | Find /c "iexplore"` and if you know the titlebar you can use that as well.

Comment: that's not possible to determine since that information is internal to the browser. For example in Chrome the more extensions you have, the more processes will be created, even if you have only one tab. @CatCat that depends on the browser. Classic Firefox has only one process for all, and they they gradually introduced more processes for rendering and addons. And unlike Chrome, in FF Quantum the number of processes is limited to 4

Comment: Internet Explorer is part of the Windows SDK. It's the only one Windows programmers use as it's the only one that is programmable.

Comment: @CatCat who said that the OP is using IE? Starting a URL will open it in the default browser. And who said that other browsers are not programmable? Have you ever heard of Selenium?

Comment: He is a programmer.

Comment: I got the idea now, thanks. Will try the tasklist or ill try another approach.